# Issue with building .NET Framework 4.6.1 project

Tags: .net, msbuild, frameworks, .net-4.6.1

I have bamboo build server. And I try to build there our old project with Target Framework .Net Framework 4.6.1

First step was completed successfully.

```
nuget restore .\Host.csproj
```

But I got error on next build step
I used MSBuild2019 utility for build project.

And I get error

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.410\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, version 1.1.0 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [C:\Atlassian\Bamboo-home\local-working-dir\216039426\ACLTI-ALBB-JOB1\Host.csproj]
```

What can be cause of this error?

I am confused by this line

```
 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.410\Sdks
```

Why I see sdk 5 ?

Comment: How are you building? What is your command line? Are you trying to build with the `dotnet` tool? The `dotnet` tool doesn't support .NET Framework.

Comment: Hello @JonathanDodds
I use msbuild to build project

msbuild .\Host.csproj /t:build /p:TransformConfigFiles=true /verbosity:normal /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=LtiApi  /maxcpucount:6 /p:RestorePackages=false

Comment: Do you have the "[Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/)" or "Visual Studio 2019" installed on the build host machine? Is "[.NET Framework 4.6.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net461)" installed?

Comment: @JonathanDodds
I installed DevPack https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net461 So this pack installed .NET Framework 4.6.1
VS 2019 was not installed

Comment: What version is MSBuild? Is it v16 or later? Where is MSBuild installed? What is the "MSBuild2019 utility for build project" that you mentioned?

Comment: I used msbuild by next path c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe

Comment: From the "Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools" part of the path, the "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" have been installed. `msbuild --version` should show a major version of v16.

Comment: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

16.11.2.50704

Comment: Do you have a "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" file and are you running that batch file to set-up the environment for the build tools? Among other things, it will add `msbuild` to the `PATH`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253473/discussion-between-roman-and-jonathan-dodds).